# A discord damage calculator bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

Currently I am working on a discord bot for a Pokemon and I will be running, I have the encounter system down, but have been having trouble with the damage system. Currently this is what the whole code looks like.

```
import discord
import os
import random
import asyncio
client = discord.Client()
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('aaaaand were scuffed'.format(client))

###Biome encounter list###
DesertList2 = ['charmander', 'charmeleon', 'charizard']

###commands###
#desert enc
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!desert'):
        mon = random.choice(DesertList2)
        print(mon)
        await message.channel.send(mon)

@client.event
async def damage(ctx, num1, num2, num3): 
    result = (num1+num2)/num3
    await ctx.send(result)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Note(s): I have client.run, just not shown for obvious reasons.

Comment: We are not a coding service. Please explain what the issue is, what you have tried, and any error messages you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@2P1XLS I took the liberty of making your `desert` command an actual command, since it was previously in the `on_message` event, and it seems to me that you're trying to use it as a command. However, you can still run it how you were running it previously: `!desert`. I've also added the `await client.process_commands(message)` in the `on_message` event, since that's where it belongs. Try this out:

```py
import discord
import os
import random
import asyncio
client = discord.Client()
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('aaaaand were scuffed'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    await client.process_commands(message)

###Biome encounter list###
DesertList2 = ['charmander', 'charmeleon', 'charizard']

###commands###
#desert command
@client.command()
async def desert(ctx):
    mon = random.choice(DesertList2)
    print(mon)
    await ctx.send(mon)

#damage command
@client.command()
async def damage(ctx, num1 : int, num2 : int, num3 : int): 
    result = (num1 + num2) / num3
    await ctx.send(result)
```

If you run `!damage 1 2 4`, then it would do `(1+2)/4` and would return `0.75`. I've tried this code out myself, so it should definitely work. Make sure to copy it exactly. Hope this helped you!

Comment: IT WORKED! Hurray! Finally I can rest... rest assured that I have a load of more work to do... But thank you so much, have a nice valentines day tomorrow!

Comment: @2P1XLS Let's go! I'm so happy it worked for you. Have a nice valentines day tomorrow too!

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice this, hope yours is a blast too!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create separate argument variables.

```py
@client.command()
async def damage(ctx, num1 : int, num2 : int, num3 : int): # for your 1 2 4 example, 3 number arguments would be sufficient
    result = (num1+num2)/num3
    await ctx.send(result)
```

This would do (1+2)/4 and should give you 0.75.

Also, after looking at your imgur image, this is what your `on_message` function needs to look like:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!desert'):
        mon = random.choice(DesertList2)
        print(mon)
        await message.channel.send(mon)

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: This should be perfect! Thanks a lot, I was holding off a lot of stuff cause I didnt have this lol

Comment: No problem. Remember to click the accept answer button below the downvote button next to my post if it helped you out!

Comment: Hey, Aditya. I was just wondering if the command is already set somehow and what I would have to do to have it do the math? Or how to set the command, I have a prefix and all, just not sure why it's not sending any messages.

Comment: Hey, @2P1XLS. Let's say that your prefix is `!`. To run the command, you would have to do `!damage 1 2 4`, and this should print out the message. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yo, for some reason didnt work, I think its something to do with ```@client.event```, rn my code is 
```@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('!desert'):
        mon = random.choice(DesertList2)
        print(mon)
        await message.channel.send(mon)
@client.event
async def damage(ctx, num1, num2, num3): # for your 1 2 4 example, 3 number arguments would be sufficient
    result = (num1+num2)/num3
    await ctx.send(result)```

edit: sorry for the weird format, new to the site.

Comment: @2P1XLS it isn't working because you're supposed to write `@client.command async def damage(ctx, num1, num2, num3):` instead of `@client.event async def damage`.

Comment: @2P1XLS I've edited my original answer to change it from `bot.command()` to `client.command()`. Copy my code exactly and it should work without any issues.

Comment: I took a picture of my code [here](https://imgur.com/a/hjeXXu2) and put it on imgur, I really gotta go to bed, but I'm not in a rush so you can do this tomorrow if you want.

Comment: @2P1XLS omg I finally realized what's going on. There's nothing wrong with your command. Add
`await client.process_commands(message)` at the bottom of your `on_message` function. Make sure it is not indented under any of your previous `if` conditions. You need this line so that your bot can process if the message is calling a command, so unless you add this line, none of your commands will work!

Comment: I've edited my original code again to show you what your `on_message` function should look like. Hopefully this works now. If this helps you out, make sure to click the accept answer button under the downvote button next to my post!

Comment: Ill try it right after I get out of school, no need to worry ill remember to click answer. Thanks so much for all the help, I learned a lot!

Comment: This has become quite the doozy, huh. Currently, my [code](https://imgur.com/a/bRUWaCT) still won't work, I doubt it's you, it most likely is due to me having a lottttttttttt of homework I jammed into last night. I am extremely new to discord coding, but also pretty sure that 2 @client.events is bad? If not please to tell me.

Comment: @2P1XLS Your code has a few mistakes, which can only be fixed if you clearly read what I'm writing. I don't mean to be rude since you are new to discord coding, but you need to make sure you're reading what I'm writing and implementing it exactly. I want you to copy your code, edit your original question, and paste the code in there, so that it's easier for me to copy and fix, instead of me having to write out all your code myself. After you do that, comment here that you've done it, and I'll fix your code and post it as a new answer in this forum.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a clean and simple effective way of a calculator command, you can give it endless arguments for it to calculate

By using `*`, you can pass multiple numbers and `.join` will join each of the arguments you pass. Here's a simple example,

```
@client.command()
async def calculate(ctx, operation, *nums):
    if operation not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        await ctx.send('Please use a valid operation type')
        return
    var = f' {operation} '.join(nums)
    await ctx.send(f'{var} = {eval(var)}')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wanted a solution where he wouldn't have to specify an operation type

Comment: Yeah but its fine, thanks for your help anyway though! I may use this later, who knows!